# How to properly use AxMsRdpClient in C# .NET

Tags: c#, activex, rdp

Before posting, I have researched everything I could, did many tests and came to no conclusion. It is not documented clearly how to use *AxMsRdpClient* properly.

I have a small development application that I wish to use for RDP connections with the remote endpoints being Windows Server 2008 - 2019.

```
AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting client = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
client.Server                            = "123...";
client.Domain                            = "";
client.UserName                          = "Administrator";

MsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting sec = (MsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting)client.GetOcx();
sec.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword = "...";
sec.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;

client.Connect();
```

The moment I set ClearTextPassword, it will fail with an unclear error (*An authentication error has occurred*).

I have tried every combination possible, from client.AdvancedSettings2 - client.AdvancedSettings9 and IMsRdpClientNonScriptable to MsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting, every combination, all have the same result.

I've also checked the event logs on both my machine and the remote server, no hints or errors.

At this point I am out of options and seeking some professional help and explanation as to why on earth is it so hard to use this plugin.

I wish to understand:

- Why does it not work and how to debug it
- What's the numbering!? Checking the functions description I understand each has its own client support starting Vista, etc, but seriously?!

Many thanks

**-- Update 1 --**

After messing around for hours and hours, adding a dummy Domain makes the connection work:

```
client.Domain = "domain";
```

No idea why this is required, and why a dummy value works.

**-- Update 2 --**

Removing the client Domain and instead adding the machine name next to the username seems to work as well:

```
client.UserName = System.Environment.MachineName + "\\" + username;
```

Once again, no idea why.

Comment: Domain is a big deal, the account+password needs to be know by both ends of the connection.  Beware that you [might be mislead](https://superuser.com/questions/1589681/rdp-login-with-domain-account-fails) by a cached domain name.  Best to be explicit about the domain name, "." means same-as-login-domain.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, very informative! None of the articles found, even here, mention this. Which is why I would like to have a canonical answer.

Comment: You can use "." (dot) as a domain name, which means this computer, or you can use [domain]\[user] or [machine]\[user] format where it derives the authentication realm from. A user exists somewhere, and you need to tell it where. If it is a domain user, use the domain name, if not use the computer name since that user exists only on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how you can encapsulate your remoteDesktop Manager using AxRdpClient

```cs
public class RemoteDesktop
{
    private AxMsRdpClient rdpClient;

    public RemoteDesktop(AxMsRdpClient rdpClient)
    {
        this.rdpClient = rdpClient;
    }

    public void Connect(string server, string username, string password)
    {
        rdpClient.Server = server;
        rdpClient.UserName = username;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = password;
        rdpClient.Connect();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        rdpClient.Disconnect();
    }

    public void SetEventHandlers()
    {
        rdpClient.OnDisconnected += RdpClient_OnDisconnected;
    }

    private void RdpClient_OnDisconnected(object sender, AxMSTSCLib.IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent e)
    {
        // Handle the OnDisconnected event
    }
}
```

and this is how to use it

```cs
RemoteDesktop remoteDesktop = new RemoteDesktop(axMsRdpClient1);
remoteDesktop.SetEventHandlers();
remoteDesktop.Connect("server name or IP address", "username", "password");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the question I'm afraid. Please read my question, it's about the actual domain/username issue.